Is there a halakhic basis for the position of Chief Rabbi of a country whose authority must be acknowledged by all Jewish citizens?
Wikipedia lists 39 countries which have one or more Chief Rabbis, counting the United Kingdom and Commonwealth as one rabbinate. Israel is the only country in which the Ashkenazi and Sephardic Chief Rabbis are government positions which regulate halakhic matters pertaining to all Jewish citizens.
Since Israel is a unique country, I am asking about other countries with Jewish populations and the quasi-governmental office of "Chief Rabbi," considered to be "the recognized religious leader of that country's Jewish community, or to a rabbinic leader appointed by the local secular authorities."
In countries with small, long-established Jewish communities it is likely that the Chief Rabbi's office will overlap closely with the traditional ethno-religious Jewish population. That rabbi will be the agreed upon halakhic authority of the community. For example, Iran has approximately 9,000 Jewish citizens. The three most recent Chief Rabbis of Iran have been the rabbis of The Yusef Abad Synagogue (Sukkot Shalom Synagogue), the main synagogue in Teheran.
With a Jewish population of approximately 300,000, Great Britain has representative populations of Orthodox, Haredi, Masorti, and Reform Jews. However, the Office of the Chief Rabbi is held by the Orthodox Chief Rabbi of the United Hebrew Congregations of Great Britain and the Commonwealth. This is a quasi-governmental position, as Great Britain has an Established Religion, whose leaders are permanent members of the House of Lords. While Chief Rabbis have been knighted and made Life Peers, they are not automatically members of the government.
Since Britain has a heterogeneous Jewish population, does the Chief Rabbi hold halakhic authority over British Jews outside of the United Hebrew Congregations (Orthodox)?

I don't think so. In Europe it was very common to have an official government rabbi, and then an actual rabbi that people listened to.

No. The chief Rabbi is not the foremost halachic authority, even within the United Synangogue. His official title is "Rosh Beth Din" - an almost ceremonial position. The position is more of a statesman or representative. That's not to mention the more haredi strands of British Jewry, who don't acknowledge his authority at all
